# Asp.Net MVC 5 custom action routing under an area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

i am currently trying to generate this url "/Cloud/Hosting/RoaringPenguin/Manage/Exclusions".

Here is the area registration

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Hosting_default",
            "Cloud/Hosting/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

here is the controller

```
    public class RoaringPenguinController : PortalControllerBase
{


    public ActionResult Exclusions()
    {
        return View("Exclusions");
    }


}
```

i have tried added a route onto the action itself like so

```
[Route("Manage/Exclusions")]
public ActionResult Exclusions()
```

I have also tried adding some attributes to the controller itself

```
[RouteArea("Hosting")]
[RoutePrefix("RoaringPenguin")]
public class RoaringPenguinController : PortalControllerBase
```

but that doesn't seem to work either. If i leave all the attributes off then the final url i get is "/Cloud/Hosting/RoaringPenguin/Exclusions".
Does anyone know how i can get the "Manage" in the url as well?

Just to confirm i have the following set in my RegisterRoutes method under the RouteConfig class

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your default area route doesn't allow for the "Manage/Exclusions" part on the end. If you made the URL just `/Cloud/Hosting/RoaringPenguin/Exclusions` (minus the `Manage` part of the path) it would work fine.

If you need the route to be exactly that, then attribute routing is your best bet. However, your mentioned attempts at that are all missing something or another. Your controller should be decorated with both `RouteArea` and `RoutePrefix` to compose the first part of the path:

```
[RouteArea("Hosting", AreaPrefix = "Cloud/Hosting")]
[RoutePrefix("RoaringPenguin")]
public class RoaringPenguinController : Controller
```

However, it's typical to actually implement a base controller when dealing with areas, so that you can specify `RouteArea` in just one place:

```
[RouteArea("Hosting", AreaPrefix = "Cloud/Hosting")]
public class HostingBaseController : Controller

[RoutePrefix("RoaringPenguin")]
public class RoaringPenguinController : HostingBaseController
```

Then, on your action:

```
[Route("Manage/Exclusions")]
public ActionResult Exclusions()
```

As you had.

Comment: Hi Chris,

i tried the first suggestion (without the base controller) but all i get is a 404 error

`Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Cloud/Hosting/RoaringPenguin/Manage/Exclusions

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1069.1`

Comment: There's something else going on. Either the area isn't being registered properly, attribute routing is not enabled properly, or another route is conflcting with this. Based on what you've posted, this should work. If anything is not correct, like your area is not actually just `Hosting`, but something like `CloudHosting`, then you should make the necessary corrections to the code.

Comment: You were correct.
Basically my Attribute routing was being called after my area registration.
This is the solution
`            // attribute routing
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            // area registration
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
`

after i made that change your initial solution worked. Many Thanks!

Comment: It somehow, helped me to exactly learn about MVC Attribute Routing for Areas.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
[RouteArea("AreaName", AreaPrefix = "Cloud/Hosting")]
[RoutePrefix("RoaringPenguin")]
public class SampleController : Controller
{
     [Route("Manage/Exclusions")]
     public ActionResult Exclusions()
    {
         return View("Exclusions");
    }
}
```

or

```
[RoutePrefix("Cloud/Hosting/RoaringPenguin")]
public class RoaringPenguinController : PortalControllerBase
{

    [Route("Manage/Exclusions")]
    public ActionResult Exclusions()
   {
       return View("Exclusions");
    }

}
```

This will be the first line

```
  routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

After that only you have to write this line

```
 AreaRegistration.RegistrationAllAreas();
```